# Facebook Graph API Batch - Iterative paging

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm trying to get all posts from a number of public Facebook pages. The following combined with some paging does this but it's slow as separate calls are required to traverse through each page of posts (and then comments and then replies if these are included).

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/feed?fields=id&access_token="$TOKEN
```

From what I can find in the facebook API documentation it seems like the [batch endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests) is better for this but I'm having trouble getting all pages of posts.

The following takes the initial request and traverses forward one page (ie returning a total of 2 pages) but I can't get more than 2 pages.

```
curl \
-F 'access_token='$TOKEN \
-F 'batch=[{ "method":"GET","name":"getfeed","omit_response_on_success":false,"relative_url":"FacebookDevelopers/feed?fields=id"},
           { "method":"GET","omit_response_on_success":false,"relative_url":"FacebookDevelopers/feed?fields=id&after={result=getfeed:$.paging.cursors.after}"}]' \
https://graph.facebook.com
```

**Is there a way to get all posts from a public page using the batch endpoint?**

Comment: What do you need “all posts” for? If the pages are old enough and post frequently, that could go into the thousands, or even 5 or 6 digit figures … there is no reasonable way to fetch all that data via API. And anyway, the API is mostly geared towards working with “recent” data, and not to provide a “history” going all the way back to the very beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each paging request you will the cursor parameter (for the `after` call). You can "nest" the batch calls only one level deep, you so can indeed only request two pages at the same time.

Besides the technical limitation, please also be aware that [scraping is not allowed](https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php) and there are [request throttling limits](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/api-rate-limiting).